# Product.list works fine, but Product.info returns product not exists (Error 101)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, magento, xml-rpc

As the subject says, really. An RPC to list products according to a given filter works fine, but when I try to call product.info on a product, Magento insists that the product does not exist. I can't find any working examples for using product.info with Ruby, but if anyone's got one out there I'd be incredibly grateful.

The code that returns error 101 is:

```
client.call('call', session_id, 'product.info', [:sku, 'ProductXYZ'])
```

.. where ProductXYZ is a sku listed by Product.list beforehand. Assume that the session ID is valid and such :)

Edit: I should point out that my experience of using the same system on PHP leads me to believe Magento is probably not searching by sku, but I'm not sure how to persuade it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with your call. You are passing in `:sku` and the string but you aren't telling the web service that they are connected. Try this:

`client.call('call',session_id,'product.info',[:sku =>'ProductXYZ'])`

Or maybe this:

`client.call('call',session_id,'product.info',{:sku =>'ProductXYZ'})`

Comment: I think that may have been another typo on my part, apologies - your first example is actually the code that I've been using. Tried the second, no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a space after your sku:

```
client.call('call', session_id, 'product.info', [:sku, 'ProductXYZ '])
```

instead of

```
client.call('call', session_id, 'product.info', [:sku, 'ProductXYZ'])
```

This helps in case your sku is numeric like 12345